# Split Line at Point in FME

Tags: point, line, fme-form, splitting, fme-transformer

I need to split a network consisting of connected lines in FME by points. Do you know which transformation works in FME the same way as 'split line at point' in ArcGIS. PointOnLineOverlayer couldn't help me.

Comment: I think you can try Chopper transformer

Comment: @Ram Chopper splits the line at VERTEX or LENGTH. in this case I have a Line und Points and the Line musst be splited at Points.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the [PointOnLineOverlayer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/pointonlineoverlayer.htm).

> Performs a point-on-line overlay. Each input line is split at its closest place to any point within the specified point tolerance, and attributes may be shared between related points and lines (spatial join).

Can you explain why this transformer does not work for you? I created a sample network and splitted a line of it without problems.

Comment: I have a complicated network. in this network the lines are connected to each other. I first aggregate the lines to get a line then I have 10 points that need to split my line. When I use PointOnLineOverlayer I get the line I had before the aggregator. That means instead of 11 lines, I get 55,000 lines that are not cut out on the point

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. I think you need to change the order of things to first split the lines, and then create the collection. But maybe someone proves me wrong :)

Comment: you can see my question in FME Community too. https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D74Q000009LPCySAO/detail?s1oid=00D30000000ePES&s1nid=0DB0c000000Gmzx&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0054Q00000Ex0im&emtm=1660297820424&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0